# Why are the irrationals zero-dimensional in the Euclidean metric topology?

Tags: general-topology

In example 30/31 subpart 9 of Steen & Seebach's "Counterexamples in topology" it states that both the rationals ($\mathbb{Q}$) and the irrationals ($\mathbb{R-Q}$) are zero-dimensional in the topology induced by the usual Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

I can see an argument for why this should be so for $\mathbb{Q}$; for each $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ the balls $B_{\epsilon}(q)$ where $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R-Q}$, are both open and closed since they have no boundary points in $\mathbb{Q}$, and hence form a base of clopen sets.

But what about $\mathbb{R-Q}$?

Comment: take rational radii only.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma rational + irrational = irrational so the limit points of the balls are still in $\mathbb{R-Q}$

Comment: @HennoBrandsma oh ok.. I just realized, you could make the centers of the balls rational aswell, and then take their intersection with the irrationals. Then given an arbitrary irrational and radius you can always find a ball with that radius covering it.

Comment: yes that works too. It’s the standard countable base for the reals intersected with the irrationals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All sets of the form $(p,q) \cap \Bbb P, p < q, p,q \in \Bbb Q$ form a clopen base for $\Bbb P$, the space of irrationals. Also $\Bbb P \simeq \Bbb N^\omega$ (via continued fractions), which is another way of seeing it.

Comment: what is $(p,q)\cup\mathbb{P}$ ?

Comment: @Ben all irrationals strictly between $p$ and $q$, I.e. the open interval $(p,q)$ intersected with the set of irrationals.

Comment: doh! of course. I was overthinking it.